# How to see files checked out at specific revisions?

Tags: perforce

Say I've synced Perforce to a changelist, but a specific file to a specific revision other than the one in the changelist:

```
$ p4 sync //depot/...@500 //depot/main/Foo/bar.txt@42
```

What command can I run to tell me that Foo/Bar.txt is synced to a different revision than the one specified by the changelist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p4 sync -n //depot/...@500
```

Files that are already synced to @500 won't report anything, but for Foo/bar.txt you'll get an "updating" message because it's at a different revision.

Another approach would be:

```
p4 diff2 -q //depot/...@500 //depot/...#have
```

Again, this is just comparing @500 vs what you have synced; most of your files will be identical and report no output, but Foo/bar.txt will show up as a diff.